# Get name of category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, adminhtml

I need get the name of category from ('catalog/product') table in Magento 1.9. How can I do it ? Main table is ('productlabels/category')

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('productlabels/category')->getCollection(); 
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array('category' => $collection->getTable('catalog/category')), 'main_table.id_category = category.entity_id')
        ->joinLeft(array('labels' => $collection->getTable('productlabels/table_labels')), 'main_table.id_label = labels.id_label');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Also I have an edit form where I need to output my edit data.

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{   
    $helper = Mage::helper('productlabels');
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Name'),
        'index'  => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('category_page_image', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Label Image'),
        'index'  => 'category_page_image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'renderer' => 'Plumrocket_Productlabels_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'align' => 'center',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just check data by `print_r($model);` and check index for name

Comment: there have not index for name, i need add his

Comment: you must need name in your collection,  check your collection and set index value accordingly for column

Comment: table (productlabels/category) containst column(id_entity - primary key, id_category - index field and id_label  - index field) i join magento table (catalog/category) and i dont know how i can add name of category

Answer (score 0):

Try it now :

```
 'label' => $helper->__($model->getName()),
```

Comment: it return null.

Comment: make var_dump ($ collection), look at the index of the category name, and write it    'header' => 'yourNameCategory',

Answer (score 0):

It is right answer. Thank you for those who trying help me.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');
    $collection->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(array('category' => $collection->getTable('productlabels/category_check_list')), 'e.entity_id = category.id_category')
        ->joinLeft(array('labels' => $collection->getTable('productlabels/table_labels')), 'category.id_label = labels.id_label');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{   
    $helper = Mage::helper('productlabels');
    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Name'),
        'index'  => 'name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('category_page_image', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Label Image'),
        'index'  => 'category_page_image',
        'type' => 'image',
        'renderer' => 'Plumrocket_Productlabels_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Image',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'align' => 'center',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```